# How Can I export my server Node.js to install it on other computer? I'm using Ubuntu and I want to export on windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, ubuntu

I have create a web site on my computer using Ubuntu, Node.js, Sails.js.  And I want to work on other pc using windows 10.  How can I do it please?

Comment: just put your application to new computer and install node set path in environment variables and run your app through cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a copy of the website folder and paste into on the windows computer
2. Install node.js on the windows machine

> https://nodejs.org/en/download/

3. Install git for windows

> https://git-for-windows.github.io/

4. Open the website folder with `gitbash` command line run your project with the same steps you were following in ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS: Go to [NodeJS.org](https://nodejs.org/en/), download and install it

Dependencies: You should list all your dependencies in your package.json and use npm (comes with node) to install them.

If you need further help with NodeJS and NPM see [this post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows) for example

You can copy the rest of your source files to the other computer and should be good to go.

To further enhance your experience developing on multiple machines i highly recommend using git and a git hoster, there are multiple git hosters. Examples: GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket.